# Is it possible for misclassification rate to increase as training episodes increases in Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am using neural networks for classification

While using different training epochs/episodes, I noticed that sometimes the misclassification rate increased after a training episode eventhough the number of training has increased as well.

I expected the misclassification rate to reduce as the training episodes increased but that didn't happen at some points, for example, the error decreased from 1000 to 3000 training episodes and then it increased after 4000 episodes. So I just want to know if this is normal and if this is a sign of the network overfitting the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the learning rate and momentum is too high, the misclassification rate against **training data** should **decrease** with increased number of epochs. However, the misclassification rate against **validation or test data** might increase after a number of epochs. In this case, it is a sign of overfitting.